# iPhone: UITableView reorder rows button

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView with custom table row. What I need is to have possibility to reorder rows. so in ViewDidLoad i add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.myTableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];
}
```

also add next methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
 }


    - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   return YES;
 }
```

Also I set bg color for my custom table row:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSString *customTableRow = @"customTableRow";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
    customTableRow];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"customTableRow"
        owner:self options:nil];
    if (nib.count > 0) {
        cell = self.customTableRow;
    }
}
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(228.0f/255.0f)
    green:237.0f/255.0f blue:244.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
return cell;
}
```

And then I run my app and I had an unexpected view:

[image]

So I have tow questions:
   1.So why it so ? Reorder button is not transparent ??
   2.How to change that button to my on image ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing the background color of the `contentView`. Have you tried changing the background color of the cell itself in `-tableView:willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I didn't, but I will. What about question number 2 ?

Comment: You could probably try iterating through the cell's subviews and replacing the button with your own?

Comment: Alexsander, I'm sorry but changing the background color of the cell  (and not its content view) doesn't have any visible effect on the cell. Also, the reorder control is not included in the subviews of the cells.